# ruby and IRB find installed gems, but eclipse cannot

Tags: ruby, eclipse

I am a beginner  with Ruby development, so apologies this is a face palm question.

On mac OSX I installed ruby 1.9.3, and then installed a gem via command  'gem install selenium-webdriver', I then installed eclipse as IDE.

I then wrote a simple class requiring the 'selenium-webdriver' gem.

```
class Cheese
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'selenium-webdriver'
  ... rest of code class.
```

I can run cheese.rb without issue from the command line using irb or ruby (i.e. ruby ./path to file/cheese.rb)', but when running the script via the eclipse GUI i get an error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- selenium-webdriver (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Users/bryan/Documents/workspace/New Se Project/Cheese.rb:3
```

This would indicate a config issue with Eclipse. Note the installed default ruby version is 1.9.3 from rvm - list, but Eclipse is still 'bound' to 1.8. Googling indicates this is probably a PATH issue, but i'm not familiar with environment variables on Mac OSx.

**How can i reconfigure Eclipse (or Aptana) to 'see' the installed gems? **

Further info:

```
Bryans-MacBook-Air:Library bryan$ which ruby
/Users/bryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby

Bryans-MacBook-Air:Library bryan$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/bryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/bryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/bryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/bryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
     - /Users/bryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
    - http://rubygems.org/


Bryans-MacBook-Air:Library bryan$  echo $PATH
/Users/bryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/bryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/bryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/bryan/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Comment: Did you understand how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I first tried this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/

This did not help.

Then I saw this entry in superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/154292/ruby-rubygems-why-do-i-always-get-error-messages-when-trying-to-install-gems and running gem install using sudo helped me.

Comment: Using sudo will circumvent the environment that RVM makes - so you will just end up installing the gems into whatever global non-rvm controlled installation of Ruby you have.